# Changing the language of the web application in java

Tags: java, web-applications, resourcebundle

Can any one tell me how to change the language of the web application in java without using properties file.

For instance
If the browser's language is in french then the web application text has to change into french.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to use the [`Accept-Language` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). For instance:

```
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;
```

Usually you build your application on top of a Framework (e.g. Spring) and/or a technology (e.g. JSF) which takes care of this problem for you and gives you the correct `Locale` of the user.

Based on the `Locale`, you retrieve the correct version of a given message. Typically, you will have multiple properties file (one for each language). This will be also managed by the framework or the technologie you are using.

Actually, you definitively have to tell us more about your application if you want a precise answer.

Comment: In my application i will be using only jsp, java. Not JSF, so how can i do. can you please give me an example.